# Identify the Click Event in bootstrap touch spin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am little bit confusion to find the click event in the class using jquery.
my question is how to identify **whether I click touchspin down or up**
I am using bootstrap touch spin.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default bootstrap-touchspin-down">-</button>
<input type="number" value="18" onchange="calculatetotal(3)" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; display: block;" class="ex_limit form-control" readonly="" id="qty3">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default bootstrap-touchspin-up">+</button>
```

I Want to calculate some process in  when Up botton clicked and some process in down button click.

Here I try to Identify the button using class.

```
$('.btn, .btn-default, .bootstrap-touchspin-down').click(function(){
    alert("down!");
});
```

Please help me to do this task.

Comment: Just use `$('.bootstrap-touchspin-down').click(function(){ ... })` instead, comma separated lists mean multiple elements

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear I got It @Darren Sweeney

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('[class*="bootstrap-touchspin-"]').click(function(event) {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.hasClass('bootstrap-touchspin-down')) {
    alert('down');
  } else if ($this.hasClass('bootstrap-touchspin-up')) {
    alert('up');
  }
});
```

Alternatively:

```
$('.bootstrap-touchspin-down').click(function(event) {
  alert('down');
});

$('.bootstrap-touchspin-up').click(function(event) {
  alert('up');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

better and easy way is to handle change event like given below

```
  $('input[name=\'cart-quantity\']').on("change",function(event){
    alert("hi")
})
```